# How can I strip only HTML tags, not their contents?

Tags: jquery, html, xpath

I'm trying to remove the HTML tags that have at least one attribute from string. But I need to keep their contents. So suppose this string:

```
<div>
    <p>These line shall stay</p>
    <p class="myclass">Remove this one</p>
    <p>But keep this</p>
    <div style="color: red">and this</div>
    <div style="color: red">and <p>also</p> this</div>
    <div style="color: red">and this <div style="color: red">too</div></div>
</div>
```

I want this output:

```
<div>
    <p>These line shall stay</p>
    Remove this one
    <p>But keep this</p>
    and this
    and <p>also</p> this
    and this too
</div>
```

How can I do that?

---

Actually [I can do that by PHP](https://3v4l.org/9qHRM):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@*]") as $node) {
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    while ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $parent->insertBefore($node->lastChild, $node->nextSibling);
    }
    $parent->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As you see it works as well, but now I need to do that by javascript *(or jQuery)*. Well how can I do that? Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$('.myTextArea *').each(function(){
    if (this.attributes.length)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Php's strip_tags() ?

Comment: @Progrock As I said, I can do that by PHP. Now I need to do that by JS. by the way, no `strip(tags)` remove all tags, in this case I need to remove the tags that have at least one attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with this function, which follows almost the same logic as your PHP code:

```js
function cleanHtml(html) {
    var $doc = $('<span>' + html + '</span>');
    $('*', $doc).each(function (index, el) {
        if (!$(el).parents().addBack().is('pre') &&
                el.hasAttributes('attributes')) {
            while ($(el).contents().length) {
                $(el).contents().last().insertAfter(el);
            }
            $(el).remove();
        }
    });
    return $doc.html();
}

// I/O for snippet
$('button').click (function () {
    // get HTML from input textarea
    var dirtyHtml = $('.myTextArea').val();
    // clean it
    var html = cleanHtml(dirtyHtml);
    // put cleaned HTML back in textarea
    $('.myTextArea').val(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="myTextArea" style="width:100%" rows=10>  
<div>
    <p>These line shall stay</p>
    <p class="myclass">Remove this one</p>
    <p>But keep this</p>
    <div style="color: red">and this</div>
    <pre>do not touch <div class="myclass">this div in code</div></pre>
    <div style="color: red">and <p>also</p> this</div>
    <div style="color: red">and this <div style="color: red">too</div></div>
</div>
</textarea>

<button>Clean</button>
```

Comment: Seems nice .. upvote. Just one thing, what do you think about @Derek Story's solution?

Comment: Dereks's code destroys too many tags. Did you try it on your sample HTML?

Comment: Yeah I've tested it .. apparently it works as well http://i.stack.imgur.com/34X9O.png

Comment: Check again:  `<p>also</p>` is rendered `also`, while it should keep the tag.

Comment: Ok, just one thing, executing your code per keydown on a textarea is a normal thing?

Comment: I would use the `input` event instead of `keydown`: it triggers also when you perform changes via the context menu, or mouse dragging, ...etc. `$(...).on('input', function() { ... })`. On the other hand, if users are typing tags, then the HTML will not always be valid, giving undesired results. So take good care of what you do.

Comment: great .. thank you again. But you know, when you click on `Clean` button multiple time, the value of textarea will be empty. I mean it will remove texts.. why? what's the problem?

Comment: Ah yes: fixed that now. The original HTML needs to wrapped in a dummy tag before the loop. It will be ignored in the output. This also makes that the outer `div`, that is part of the input, stays in the result.

Comment: Look, your approach seems great .. I want to use it. But honestly I don't know how can I use it in reality. I have a variable which contains the value of a textarea, how can I pass it into your function?

Comment: OK, I have updated the code to isolate the function you need from the rest of the demo code.

Comment: Look, there isn't any new problem `:-)`  .. all fine. I just wanted to say you thanks again *(one more time)* `;-)`

Comment: Well sorry to ping you again. But I recently figured it out that I need to leave `<pre><code>` tags. I mean I need to keep all `<pre><code>`'s children intact. I mean it should ignore the tags that are wrapped into `<pre><code>` tags. I improved your condition `if (el.hasAttributes('attributes') || el == '<pre><code>') {` but it doesn't work as expected. Can you please and please *(if it is possible)* develop your code and add mentioned property to it?

Comment: I will, but it wont be as easy as that, as `el` can only be one of `pre` or `code` at a time. It is 1:20 am here, so I don't think I will manage now :-)

Comment: Ah ok .. go to sleep buddy :-) sweet dreams. by the way, ok no need to `code`, Just `pre` is enough. So everything which is into `<pre>` tag should be intact. just that.

Comment: OK, I was just going to ask that. Good, that makes it a tad easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the string and replace the entire element with it:

[JS Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjJkNQ?editors=1111)

```
$('.myTextArea *').each(function(){
    if(this.attributes.length) {
      var string = $(this).text();
      $(this).replaceWith(string)
    }
});
```

Comment: Just one thing, executing your code per keydown on textarea is a normal thing?

Comment: Given the sample HTML, it removes one `p` too many. It becomes very apparent when you have several nested tags, some with, and some without attributes.

Comment: @trincot is correct. I didn't take into account the nested tags within the direct children. His answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.myTextArea *').each(function() {
    while(this.attributes.length > 0) {
       this.removeAttribute(this.attributes[0].name);
    }
});
```

It loops through all the attribute and remove them one by one.

Comment: The OP wants to remove elements, not just remove attributes from elements.

Comment: @LarsH true ... I want to remove elements that have at least one attribute.